# ffmpeg crashes as file is in use when using drawtext filter reload

Tags: ffmpeg

Recently whilst working inside of FFMPEG ive been trying to run a script which shows the current artist based on what a textfile says the current artist is. Loading this every frame, however the file is also being written to and thus when being written to the stream crashes with..

```
The text file 'artist.txt' could not be read or is empty
Error while filtering
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
```

The line im using to write the artist.txt into the content is as follows..

```
-vf "drawtext=enable='gte(t,3)':fontfile=fonts/Dosis-Bold.ttf:textfile=artist.txt:reload=1:y=h-line_h-10:x=(W/tw)*n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [drawtext documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for `reload` states:

> Be sure to update the file atomically, or it may be read partially, or even fail.

For example in Linux, after each update to the source file use `mv` to overwrite `artist.txt`.